# How work with webpack and font loaders

Tags: webpack, font-face, webpack-dev-server

I have a custom css loading some custom fonts, something like that:

```
src: url("fonts/alright_sans_af/alright_sans_af_regular_italic.eot?") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/alright_sans_af/alright_sans_af_regular_italic.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/alright_sans_af/alright_sans_af_regular_italic.ttf") format("truetype");
```

I wrote the following loader in my webpack.config

```
{test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

*Module parse failed: /app/styles/fonts/alright_sans_af/alright_sans_af_regular_italic.eot? Unexpected character '' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with my loader, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Where did you obtain this font? It seems there is a syntax error in the file.

Comment: Hey randy, I got it from my work project. This font works fine. I believe the only mistake is my loader. What would wrong with this font for you? thx